# Сохранение данных в переменной после выполнения функции

Tags: javascript, html, функции, button

Итак, есть у меня "волшебная" кнопка, по нажатию на которую запускается простенькая функция:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let Gender = 0;
let Strong = 10;

function Gender1() {
  Gender = 1;
  if (Strong<15) {
  Strong = Strong+5;
  } else {
  Strong = Strong+0;
  }
  console.log(Gender);
  console.log(Strong); 
}
</script>

<button id="gen1" class="btn1" onclick="Gender1()"><img src="./image/Men.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">

<div id="tab3">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Strong</td>
      <td><div id="strong"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gender</td>
      <td><div id="pol"></div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('strong').innerHTML = Strong;
  document.getElementById('pol').innerHTML = Gender;
</script>
</div>
```

И если верить консоли, то все работает отлично,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот только когда я пытаюсь опубликовать значение этих переменных на хтмл-странице, то там публикуются значения переменных заданные по умолчанию:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Публикацию осуществую вот так:

```
  document.getElementById('strong').innerHTML = Strong;
```

Скрипт публикации данных обявлен в элементе "div"(1), в котором так же находится таблица, в которой и публикуются результаты. В коде порядок следующий: таблица, затем скрипт. Указанная выше функция, как и сама кнопка находятся за пределами этого элемента "div"(1) и выполняются намного раньше, чем строится таблица и публикуются значения переменных.
Думал проблема в том, где именно вставлен скрип (в начале хтмл файла или сразу после таблицы), но никакие манипуляции с его перемещением не помогли исправить проблему.
И так как консоль никаких проблем не видит, друзья, я нуждаюсь в вашей экспертной помощи, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вроде как let локально, var глобально. Поменяйте let на var до функции

Comment: По идее это не имеет значения. Локально - это если переменная обьявляется внутри одной, например, функции и больше нигде не используется, а глобально - это если переменная обьявлена за пределами функции и может использоваться в других местах программного кода. Кроме того, на другом моем проекте все переменные были обьявлены через let и там все прекрасно работало.

Comment: Ради эксперемента попробовал поменять  let на var - это не помогло.

Comment: А вы точно `Gender1()` где-то вызываете, а не только функцию описываете? Я попробовал, и так и так вроде выводит потом результат именно как в функции установлены переменные.

Comment: Да, больше похоже на то, что фукнция `Gender1` нигде не вызывается, поэтому значения остаются преждними. @RottenRat Рекомендую вообще забыть про var.

Comment: Она вызывается. Сейчас добавлю код.

Comment: А, так у вас вывод значений в html идёт один раз - при загрузке страницы. А нужно после срабатывания кнопки чтобы этот вывод был. Автоматом у вас ничего не обновится. Если перенести этот вывод в функцию `Gender1` в конец, то всё правильно выводится. Ну или оформите этот вывод в отдельную функцию и дёргайте из `Gender1` её. Вариантов много разных. В любом случае вам нужно как-то вывести новые значения в поля.

Comment: CrazyElf, спасибо большое, а то уже голову сломал, что не так!!! Наконец-то, все заработало как надо!

Comment: Оформлю тогда ответом )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('strong').innerHTML = Strong;
  document.getElementById('pol').innerHTML = Gender;
</script>
```

Вот этот код срабатывает только один раз - при загрузке страницы. Так что функция у вас прекрасно работает, только результат её работы вы не видите. Нужно как-то сделать вывод обновлённых данных, например, оформив код вывода отдельной функцией и запускать эту функцию и при старте страницы и в конце вашей функции. Примерно так:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
let Gender = 0;
let Strong = 10;

function Gender1() {
  Gender = 1;
  if (Strong<15) {
  Strong = Strong+5;
  } else {
  Strong = Strong+0;
  }
  console.log(Gender);
  console.log(Strong); 

  ShowData() // <-- вывод данных
}
</script>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowData()
{
  document.getElementById('strong').innerHTML = Strong;
  document.getElementById('pol').innerHTML = Gender;
}
ShowData() // <-- вывод данных
</script>
```